# connect websocket to ubuntu server hosted in virtualbox

Tags: java, ubuntu, websocket, glassfish, virtualbox

I've created a basic java EE 7 chat application - with Intellij Ultimate 14 - that lets users send messages and receive messages (using sessions, no room, no user identification).

I've tried the application by itself on a glassfish 4.1 server on windows 8.1 : it works perfectly.

Now I'm trying to run it in an ubuntu 14.04 server hosted in virtualbox (same glassfish and java ee version), this is so that I can later work on clustering the application.

When I install the application on the ubuntu server, using the web based interface (that I access from the windows host), I can load the application in a chrome, but the websocket doesn't seem to connect properly and therefore I cannot send any message at all.
By the way, I've tried connecting the websocket on the glassfish installed on the windows and it works fine.

Here is the html side of the app connecting the websocket to the server :

```
    var host = "ws://" + document.location.host + "/GlassFish7_war/test";
    wsocket = new WebSocket(host);
    wsocket.onmessage = onMessage; // the function that displays received messages
```

and here is the relevant part of the server accepting the socket :

```
@ServerEndpoint("/test")
public class MyEndPoint {

   @OnOpen
   public void openConnection(Session session) {
      session.getBasicRemote().sendText("hello there !");
     // [...]
   }
}
```

you guessed it : I never receive the "hello there !" message on the client side.

I think the problem might come from the configuration of the virtualbox network, yet I can't seem to figure out what to do about it. Currently I have a bridged and a NAT adapter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Thanks a lot !